# Null conditional operator not working (shows "invoke is not a member of xxx")

Tags: vb.net

I can't seem to find anyone else having this same issue. I have seen that you can use null-conditional operators in VB.NET. E.g.

```
SendNews?.Invoke("Just in: A newsworthy item...")
```

However, I'm getting "invoke is not a member of SendNews"

I have tried setting "Option Infer On" but still getting this error.

Any ideas? (using .net 4.6.1)

Comment: What is `SendNews`?

Comment: Is SendNews a control?  .Invoke is a Control method.

Comment: Do you get the error without the "?", if yes then it has nothing to do with the null conditional operator.

Comment: If you know the type of `SendNews` _and_ that type has an `Invoke` method, the appropriate way would be `DirectCast(SendNews, YourTypeName).Invoke(...)`.

Comment: Does `SendNews?.Invoke` throw any error without the null conditional operator?

Comment: ok, i think i have misunderstood the use of this feature.  I was trying to do `if myObject isNot Nothing andalso myObject.userID > 0`  wanted to try using this operator for my if statement.  Then following that, wanted to "involk" a function, but that is an incorrect use of ?.involk.
Ill adjust my question later today, i think i need to ask more about the use of .involk

Answer (score -1):

The null conditional operator is used in place of a null check.  For instance, instead of this:

```
If SendNews IsNot Nothing Then
    SendNews.Invoke("...")
End If
```

You can shorten it to this:

```
SendNews?.Invoke("...")
```

But, that's *all* it does.  It does nothing to check if the object actually contains the members being accessed.  If you are using late binding (`Dim SendNews As Object` with `Option Strict Off`, the rough equivalent of using `dynamic` in C#), the null conditional operator will not skip the method call if it doesn't exist on the object.  It will still throw the same exception as it would have otherwise.  Currently, the only way to check if a late-bound object contains a particular method is to catch and ignore the exception or to look for it, by string name, with reflection.